# MVC No Add Controller Menu or Scaffolding Menu

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding, asp.net-mvc-controller, asp.net-mvc-5.2

Just wondering if any of you has experience the same trouble, since I downloaded the Visual Studio Express 2013 For web, the "Add Controller or Scaffolding" never appear in the menu when I created a new project.
I have updated the MVC 5.2.2 still no luck, I have Added the GUID E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47 still not showing up.

Anyone who answer very much appreciated,

Thank you

Comment: same problem... VS Express 2013 for web,