# Context menu has no "Add Scaffolding" nor "Add Controller" options

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I'm trying to get started with ASP.NET/C#, and I'm doing so by following along some guides and tutorials.

One major issue I keep running into is that I have no `Add Scaffolding` in the context menu, nor `Add Controller`.  I can't figure out a workaround for the lack of the `Add Scaffolding`.

[image: Screen Capture of the Context Menu]

---

There are various relate posts on SO. I will address some:

- [How to Add Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17623516/in-visual-studio-2013-asp-net-mvc-5-how-do-i-add-a-new-controller)

  The accepted answer says something that directly contradicts my experience.  There is no `Add Controller` option anywhere.
- [Reload the project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20600210/998328)
- [Reinstall suggested in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21501218/mvc-context-menus-missing)

  I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling several versions.  So far I've tried VS2013 Express for Web, VS2013 Community, and right now I'm using VS2013 Ultimate.  Each one has had a fresh install installed within the month.
- [Add a guid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26962562/mvc-no-add-controller-menu-or-scaffolding-menu)

  I tried adding a guid to a .proj file, an idea from another question at the moment of which I cannot find.
- [Same issue in Sep 2014, no answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25908990/asp-mvc-5-project-new-scaffolded-item-is-missing-from-the-context-menu)

  I realize there are several questions with the same issue, but none of the answers address my situation. Of the solutions I've seen proposed, I can't get any of them to work.  Maybe I'm copying the guid's in the wrong place, maybe I'm not uninstalling correctly, I'm not sure.

I haven't yet tried to uninstall everything related to VS. I have a lot of random product on this machine. I wasn't aware that, for example, "Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime (x64) or Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2.0 - ENU could disrupt VS2013 features. If anyone has information about this please let me know. I don't know the extent to which I would have to uninstall stuff in order to find the root of this issue. My Programs and Features menu is littered with MS product that I can barely tell apart.

**EDIT:**

Some Background Info:

I am using `Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 Version 12.0.31101.00 Update 4`, and `Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.5.50938`.

I used no special install instructions.

It's a web application. `File > New Project... > Installed..Templates..Visual C#..Web..ASP.NET Web Application > MVC`.

Upon Dleh's suggestion, I looked for the `Add > ...` buttons after changing the project type.  I selected `File > New Project ... > Visual Studio 2012 > ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application (.NET Framework 4.5.1) > Internet Application`, and I am confused to report that there is an `Add > Controller...` button.  I have no idea what is happening.

Also, of note, I (within the week) installed VS2013 Ultimate on my home machine, and I have having none of these issues.

[image: Confirmation of Add Controller... button]

Comment: if this is a `Microsoft` Issue.. have you tried putting in a ticket with their support desk..?

Comment: No, I'm sorry, I don't know how to do that.  I'll look into that.  Thank you.

Comment: When you installed Visual Studio, did you choose a custom setup or recommended?

Comment: Also, what version are you running? To view this go to Help > About Microsoft Visual Studio

Comment: Is this a Website, or a Web Application? (File -> New Website is website, File -> New Project then selecting ASP.NET Web Application is a Web Application)

Comment: what is your project type? that context menu keys off the project type i believe, so if the type is abnormal it may not provide that option

Comment: @CarrieKendall I am using `Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 Version 12.0.31101.00 Update 4`, and `Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.5.50938`.  I used no special install instructions.  @mason It's a web application.  `File > New Project... > Installed..Templates..Visual C#..Web..ASP.NET Web Application > MVC.`  @DLeh I will try creating various new project types.

Comment: That should be the correct project type.

Comment: @DLeh I tried other project types, and I have a screen capture of the `Add > Controller...` work flow.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant, but ASP.NET MVC 4 is two versions old so it will be worth while to get this working in a newer version (ie MVC 5 for Visual Studio 2013) if you're just starting.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have solved the issue, but I don't know exactly what I did.

[image: Evidence that it has been fixed.]

[One answer from here was part of what prompted me to uninstall a number of MS products and features.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17623516/in-visual-studio-2013-asp-net-mvc-5-how-do-i-add-a-new-controller)  Unfortunately, I can't remember the exact program or feature I uninstalled.

It seems like the uninstalling of related programs and features fixed the issue.  By "related programs and features" I mean anything in the `Control Panel > All Control Panel Items > Programs and Features` menu that had ".NET" or "Visual Studio" or "Microsoft * Web Tools" or of the like.  Many of them required a system reboot after uninstalling, and after one system reboot, the desired features in VS2013 was there.

There were on the order of 20-30 MS+VS+.NET related programs, and I uninstalled about 15.

I can't remember exactly which one I uninstalled, but it was anything that look remotely old and related to VS or .NET.  Even if it was recent, I always figured I could reinstall stuff if I got the wrong thing.

Hopefully, anyone going through a similar issue will find this helpful.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, installing

*AspNetWebTools2013_1Setup.exe*

*WebToolsExtensionsVS.msi*

fixed it for me.

Link [**Here**](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41532)